# How to pass a variable into a route in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Suppose I have

```
# a bunch of methods and instance variables here

@some_var = "this is a var"

get '/' do
    p @some_var
end

=> nil

# I'd like this to return "this is a var"!!!
```

This is as oversimplified as possible.  I've read about getting vars through the params hash, or using sessions to pass vars between routes
even a

```
before do
    @some_var = "this is a var"
end
```

But this is not what I'm after.  I'm having trouble understanding the scoping of the variables as they exist in the methods before I access them in a route.

What am I missing???

Comment: I think that what you are missing is the fact that Ruby makes it possible to change the binding of a block before executing it. So when this happens, the context in which the block executes is not the one in which it appears in the source file. How Sinatra uses this feature is beyond the scope of a comment (and beyond my knowledge of Sinatra, I'm afraid).

Comment: Hi. There's a section on Scopes and Binding in the helpful [Sinatra:README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html), it's always worth a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try settings:

```
set :foo, 'bar'

get '/foo' do
  "foo is set to " + settings.foo
end
```